# Switchable Pullup (Automotive)

Tags: digital-logic, automotive, pullup

We are looking to add to a product software-controllable pullups on sensor signal lines. Currently the signal lines we hardwire to a pullup of 5V via a 2K7 resistor, but other systems allow software-selectable pullups instead of having certain input channels always pulled up. How could we accomplish this electronically? (we can assign an MCU pin to "command" to pullup, thats fine) Is it simply a buffer that outputs when on (5V) then Hi-Z when off? Open for ideas...

Comment: Inside a MCU it is not a buffer that is used as a pullup, if that was the case, too much current could flow when that pin is then pulled down. Usually there's simply a resistor with a series switch to 5V where the switch can be programmed on/off. If that's not available on your input then you could make your own with a PMOS and a resistor. Control the PMOS's gate from the MCU.

Comment: Switching an output between 5V and hi-Z and connecting it through a resistor is fine if it will source the current you need.  Otherwise, use an external PNP or P-channel MOSFET, but always include the resistor (and a base resistor for the PNP).

Comment: Could you give an exmaple schematic with the PMOS etc please?